# SSRS 2016 form authentication in Asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication, reporting-services

i am trying to get SSRS 2016 report in my Asp.net mvc application through form authentication.when i used form authentication with iframe its redirect to login page

Comment: Your AppPool account probably doesn't have permissions to SSRS. Try adding this account in SSRS website.

Answer (score 0):

After spending few  days i am able to pass cookies instead of using I frame  i used report Viewer  to render server side report and authentic with following line

ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials=new ReportServerCards (m_reports.authcookis)

ReportServerCard is my class where my cookies generated already